# Step by Step guide for Sonar Plugin Development

Tags: plugins, sonarqube

I have gone through the http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Developing+Plugins but unfortunately it does not give detailed steps. 
Can some one help me understand how I need to call a code review tool that uses ANTLR for parsing the code files and then capture the output into Sonar
As well how do I start maintaining the rules based on XPATH for my code analysis tool on Sonar as it is done for Java/Javascript?

Answer (score 3):

A good starting point is to have a look at the code of existing plugins:
http://github.com/sonarqubecommunity

Comment: Thanks. I have started looking into those and have made some progress

Comment: there is nothing in that link

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you use the sonar dev mailing list : dev at sonar dot codehaus dot org.
Developing a Sonar plugin can't simply covered by a "guide"...

Comment: Thanks. Yes I understand that it is not simple but I am hopeful to see someone  posting their experience with antlr xpath and sonar!!!